# Creating table in Cassandra within Flink Code

Tags: cassandra, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have created keyspace and table in Cassandra from `cqlsh` shell

```
 CREATE KEYSPACE data WITH replication= {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor':1;

 CREATE TABLE test.patient(id int, heart_rate int, PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

I want to create keyspace and Table if it does not exists from Flink code, Can someone please tell me how it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can look the test case [org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.cassandra.CassandraConnectorITCase.java](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/c5b61063eebaaf46104e134a8536e2f660a3b429/flink-connectors/flink-connector-cassandra/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/cassandra/CassandraConnectorITCase.java), may be able to help you.

Answer (score -1):

[Flink-Cassandra](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/connectors/cassandra.html) connector does not have the feature to create keyspace/tables in Cassandra. You can check available methods in the connector [here](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.flink/flink-connector-cassandra_2.10/1.3.1).

If you want to create keyspace/tables in C* if they are not already created by Flink you can do:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS data WITH replication= {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor':1;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.patient(id int, heart_rate int, PRIMARY KEY(id));
```